# Centering multiple images horizontally and vertically using display: table

Tags: html, css

So using the `display: table;` technique I have centered a single image. The behaviour exhibited by this single image in the example is perfect for me; only I would like to also allow for multiple portrait images to be centered side by side in the container and centered in exactly the same manner.

```css
.slider-container {
  left: 75px;
  right: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%
}

.slider-container .table .col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center
}

.slider-container .table .col img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/images/2013/04/2014-03-Windows-Xp-Bliss-wallpaper.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle here if you prefer.](https://jsfiddle.net/simonhrogers/LyvL4jkt/2/)

This is close to what I am aiming for but would like to be able to control the size of the spacing between each image so that it is always a fixed amount – at the minute the table cells are wider than the images within them and this is cause the gap to be greater that it should be, depending on screen size:

```css
.slider-container {
  left: 75px;
  right: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%
}

.slider-container .table .row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.left-cell {
  text-align: right;

}

.middle-cell {
  text-align: center;

}

.right-cell {
  text-align: left;

}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell left-cell"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="cell middle-cell"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="cell right-cell"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/simonhrogers/q614dLsx/)

As you can see the spacing changes between the images – I would like to set it as a controllable amount. The table cell size is currently larger than the image itself which I want to prevent.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```css
.slider-container {
  left: 75px;
  right: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%
}

.slider-container .table .col {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-container .table .col img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.third {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="third"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="third"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="third"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @simon check if this what you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks this is very close to what I'm aiming for! I've amended a little in the attached fiddle to show what I mean. I'd like to be able to control the spacing between each image as well so that it is always the same set amount. 

https://jsfiddle.net/simonhrogers/q614dLsx/

Answer (score 0):

You can use *relative units* (`%`) together with the `transform` *property*:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.slider-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%; /* moved right by 50% */
  top: 50%; /* moved down by 50% */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* moved left and up by 50% of its w/h to achieve the perfect center */
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-container .table .col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.third {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%; /* modified for accuracy */
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.third > img { /* modified */
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh; /* modified, vertical responsiveness */
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="third"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="third"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="third"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simplify the structure a bit as shown below: Just have the table and a cell with three images inside it (no row necessary), and center the contents of that cell as you did. To avoid any space between the images, I added `font-size: 0` for the cell:

```css
.slider-container {
  left: 75px;
  right: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%
}

.slider-container .table .col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.slider-container .table .col img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png">
      <img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png">
      <img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```